# Save File to Desktop in Vista/Windows 7 in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, windows-vista, permissions, uac

I'm working on updating one of our applications.  It must use .NET 2.0.  One portion creates a file on the Desktop using

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath
    (Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), FileMode.Create);
```

But I get an UnauthorizedAccessException in Windows 7 (and Vista too, I'm assuming, though I haven't tested that yet).  I looked into elevation (not for the entire program, but for a separate assembly which would create the file and perform actions on it); however that seems to require .NET 3.0 or 3.5.  Is there any way to gain access to the Desktop folder using .NET 2.0?  (Requiring the program to be run as an Administrator is also not an option)

(I did a search, and the only question close to what I'm asking is this: [File creation fails in standard account (Vista)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949782/file-creation-fails-in-standard-account-vista) however it is talking about elevating the entire app and is not .NET 2.0 specific, so I believe this isn't a duplicate)

**EDIT:**
Wow, I was being really dumb.  This actually works fine.  I was trying to create a file called C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop.  Oops.  Sorry for the confusion.

EDIT: Here's the text of the exception:

```
  System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  Message="Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop' is denied."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
       at MyProgram.Prog.SaveDiagnostic(String filename, String text) in C:\Source\MyProgram\Prog.cs:line 95
       at MyProgram.Form1.buttonGenDiagnostic_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Source\MyProgram\Form1.cs:line 4729
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Northwoods.CRM.Import.Form1.Main(String[] args) in I:\WebProspect\Source\Northwoods.CRM.Import\Form1.cs:line 2616
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I think you should post complete error exception.ToString() with full trace, because this doesnt sound problem with administrator account or not. Environment.GetFolderPath will always return correct desktop for current user who is running program and current user always have full access to desktop to create/delete file on desktop path. However we did this on vista for non admin account and it does work, for Windows 7 I will be testing out soon, but I still insist you post the detailed stack trace.

Comment: It does get the correct desktop folder for current user, but I'm guessing Win7 doesn't allow programs to modify anything there.  I'll still post the full exception, though.

Comment: @Nick: the irony of this is, I generated the exact same exception when I tried to reproduce your problem. I didn't copy-and-paste your code, but I wrote something similar and got the exception, and then changed it by adding an actual file name to the path to make it work. I never noticed that your code did the same thing. I usually try to put a line break in my code samples so that I don't get the horizontal scrollbar - otherwise it's easier to miss things like this.

Comment: @Nick: I just noticed when I edited your question that you had tried to put in a line break also, but it didn't work right. This editor is weird.

Comment: You really should accept Orion's answer as his was a better cleaner answer than your own... give credit where credit's due and all that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in this code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath
    (Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), FileMode.Create);
```

Let's rewrite it into the steps that actually will occur

```
var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
var fs = new FileStream(desktopFolder, FileMode.Create);
```

What you're trying to do here is not create a file on the desktop, you are trying to *create the desktop folder itself*. The desktop folder obviously already exists, so you get an error.

What you need to do is create a file *inside* the desktop folder. You can use `Path.Combine` to do this, like this:

```
var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
var fullFileName = Path.Combine(desktopFolder, "Test.txt");
var fs = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
```

You may also want to change the FileMode to `OpenOrCreate`, or handle your exceptions - if for example the code runs twice, and the file will already exist on the second try, so you won't be able to create it a second time

Comment: I'm having the same problem OP has, but I've used your solution and it still gives me the same error. Might I need to change permission ? I'm running a windoze 8.1